# D3.js Hierarchical Edge Bundling with straight edges

Tags: svg, d3.js, hierarchy

I am trying to modify the code found [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling) so that the edges are straight and not curved.

I have tried replacing the following function

```
line = d3.lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .radius(d => d.y)
    .angle(d => d.x)
```

with

```
line = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I needed to do was to set the parameter on

```
.curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
```

from `0.85` to `0`.